# On Area 51, how do I link my profiles on existing stackexchange sites to my profile on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, profile-copying

I want to take advantage of the feature on Area 51 that recognizes my existing reputation on two other stackexchange sites. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and the other answer didn't seem to help. But I figured it out.

1. Go to your profile on any Stack Exchange site, like this one.
2. Next to
   the links that say **edit delete prefs flair my logins**, there's an
   option to create a Stack Exchange account. Click it.
3. Now you can use the "Log in with Stack Exchange" option on the Area 51 website.

Comment: Next to where? can anyone give a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Stack Exchange 1.0 sites like MathOverflow or Answers.onStartups, this is not possible because Stack Exchange 1.0 is not compatible with Stack Exchange 2.0, of which Area 51 is based off of.

---

If you are talking about a Trilogy site* or a SE 2.0 site:

1. All accounts must use the same OpenID.
2. Logout and log back in to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), a Trilogy site, or a SE 2.0 site (currently, [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), which is in ***private*** beta, is the only SE 2.0 site)

The Trilogy sites are:

- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)
- [Super User](http://superuser.com)
- [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)
- [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com)

Comment: Unless there is a lag, this doesn't work.

Comment: Is this distinction between SE sites still applicable?  Or is this answer obsolete?